# IOS many-to-many core data

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many

Good Day!

I have an app that I am working on that has two classes, ContactGroups and ContactPeople.

Many People can be in a Group, and many groups can be associated with one person.

My curiosity lies in, how does one create NSManagedObjects that I guess could be like my Group class with the person's name or ID number as the main value.

would I be doing something such as creating a new managedObject for each time a group is created?  then i save that whole managed object into core data?  I dont have much experience with core data aside from the fundamentals of just having a a couple of entities and they dont really relate to each other.

Any topics I could peruse that could be of help?  I have searched around but I might not be asking the right question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your Group class would may have some (i.e. name) or no attributes of its own and a many-to-many relationship with the Contact class.

To create a new group, you would create a new managed object and establish the relationship either by
1. Adding multiple contacts on the group object's relationship property (an NSSet of Contact objects) OR
2. Adding the group object to the relationship property for appropriate contact objects.

You'll only need to set one side of the relationship, and Core Data will take care of the inverse.

Here's the Core Data reference for relationships, there's a specific section covering many-to-many:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html

Comment: Ok,  I will check that over!  Thanks!